# $\operatorname{char}R=0 \implies\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $R$ be any field, then:

$$\operatorname{char}R=0 \implies \mathbb{Q}  \hookrightarrow R$$

Proof: 
We know that $\mathbb{Q} = Q(\mathbb{Z})=\{[(x,y)]\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z^*}:(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z^*}\}$

We consider $φ:Q(\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow R, \ [(r,s)]\longmapsto rs^{-1}$ and it's easy to prove that $φ$ is homomorphism, well ordered, and $\operatorname{ker}φ=\{[(x,y)]: φ[(x,y)]=0_R\}=\{0_{Q(\mathbb{Z})}\}$. So $φ$ is monomorphism.

Is it right? And if it is, why must $\operatorname{char}R=0$ necessary?

Comment: You need char 0 to avoid division by zero.

Comment: Specifically, if $s = \operatorname{char} R$, then $s 1_R = 0$, so you can't write $(r 1_R)(s 1_R)^{-1}$.

Comment: @SteveD Could you be more clear?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose char$\,R=p>0\;,\;\;(p\;$ a prime), then

$$\phi(p)=p\cdot\phi(1)=0\implies \phi\;\;\text{isn't injective}$$

even assuming you don't divide by zero because of some miracle.

Comment: If $ φ:Q(\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow R, [(x,y)]\longmapsto xy^{-1}$ how can we claim that? Than you for your answer.

Comment: Your map has to be a homomorphism of rings, right? There you go: just check where is $\;1\;$ mapped to.

Comment: My friend, I did not understand how you took $φ(p)$ instead of $φ([x,y])$. Our map is defined to have something with this form $[(x,y)]$ as argument. How did we pick a single prime $p$?

Comment: @Chris Thank you. No matter how you define your map, it **must** be a ring homomorphism, otherwise there is no *embedding* as algebraic structures (perhaps only as sets, if you're interested in that). Yet **you tagged** your question as ring theory: this must be clear to you! Of course, you can also argue that if  char$\,R=p\;$ then also there is no such thing as $\;rp^{-1}\;$ in that ring, as already commented below your question. BTW, if you're too worried with pairs, you can always take $\;[p,1]$ , though I think that's pointless.

Comment: @Chris take $\varphi([p,1])$ if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

The map $\chi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to R$ that maps $n$ to $n1$ (the multiple of the identity element $1\in R$ by the integer $n$) is a ring homomorphism. It is injective if and only if $\operatorname{char}R=0$. In this case this map $\chi$ can be extended to $\varphi\colon \mathbb{Q}\to R$ by
$$
\varphi\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=\chi(m)\chi(n)^{-1}
$$
(here we use injectivity, so $n\ne0$ ensures $\chi(n)\ne0$). The map $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism and it is injective, since it maps $1\in\mathbb{Q}$ to $1\in R$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, so its only ideals are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

If $R$ has characteristic $p>0$, then there is *no* ring homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{Q}\to R$ such that $f(1)=1$. The reason is very simple:
$$
f(p)=pf(1)=0
$$
so $p\in\ker f$, but since $\ker f\ne\mathbb{Q}$, it follows $\ker f=\{0\}$: contradiction.